# How to update a JavaScript object with nested array and objects under n levels?

Tags: javascript, tree, nested

Following the below tree

```
      let dumbTree = {
        name: "vob",
        uuid: "edbf146d-c9ee-4568-8c1e-a095f8ad4aff",
        children: [
          {

            name: "A0A",
            uuid: "8655460b-4862-4d11-800a-870482f4701b",
            nodeType: "project",
            children: []
          },
          {
            name: "A1A",
            uuid: "8655460b-4862-4d11-800a-870482f4701b",
            nodeType: "project",
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
```

I'd like to convert incrementally path into the same kind of structure.
In that example, I've got a path `/vob/A0A`, and `/vob/A1A`, and then if I'm clicking on the leaf `A1A`, it'd give me an array like from an API call:

`['/vob/A1A/A1A111', '/vob/A1A/A1A112', '/vob/A1A/A1A113']`, so then I'd like to populate the tree accordingly

```
  dumbTree = {
    name: "vob",
    uuid: "edbf146d-c9ee-4568-8c1e-a095f8ad4aff",
    children: [
      {

        name: "A0A",
        uuid: "8655460b-4862-4d11-800a-870482f4701b",
        nodeType: "project",
        children: []
      },
      {
        name: "A1A",
        uuid: "8655460b-4862-4d11-800a-870482f4701c",
        nodeType: "project",
        children: [
           {
              name: 'A1A111',
              children: []
           },
           {
              name: 'A1A112',
              children: []
           }
           ...
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

And then clicking on `A1AAAA` would give other children that will replace the empty array in `A1A`  sub object, etc...

Is there any efficient way to do it?

I tried something with multiple finds on nested children, but this approach isn't going to be very effective on n levels.

```js
  const testChildren2 = [
    {
      name: "AAA123",
      uuid: "00214ef8-fb29-4326-b236-3c90ab47eaaf",
      children: []
    }
  ]
```

```
      let dumbTreeIndexA = dumbTree.children.findIndex((elt) => elt.name === 'AAA')
      dumbTree.children[dumbTreeIndexA].children = testChildren2

      // vobs/AAA/AAA123
      const studyIndex = dumbTree.children[dumbTreeIndexA].children.findIndex((elt) => elt.name === 'AAA123')
```

I'm open to existing libraries such as lodash, ramdaJS, but didn't find a good way to do this yet.

Comment: Why are you using findIndex may I ask ?

Comment: Each level has a name property defined in an array of object, using findIndex I can find at each layer, which child belongs to the path with the proper index